# Show that $p \to q$ is a tautology if and only if $P \subseteq Q$.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I really don't know how to approach this.

I wrote out the truth  table for $p' + q$ in which each row has a value of $1$ apart from when $p = 1$ and $q = 0$.

Intuitively if $q = 0$ then $Q$ is a null set. And if $P\subseteq Q$ then that means $\{1\}\subseteq \{0\}$ which is false.. so this row doesn't apply.

All other rows have a value of $1$, and so the said proposition is a tautology.

Please point out if/where I'm wrong in this and how to approach this more mathematically.

Thanks.

Comment: As there is no connection between p and P and between q and Q, the problem is absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ and $Q$ ate the [truth sets](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/truth+set) for $p$ and $q$ respectively, i.e. the sets of [valuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)) that make $p$ and $q$ True respectively.

To say that $p → q$ is a *tautology* means that there is no valuation such that $p$ is True and $q$ is False,  i.e. in every valuation where $p$ is True also $q$ is True.

Thus, the truth set $P$ is a subset of $Q$.

The same for the "only if" part.